# Are wargame questions welcome?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

#### Are questions about war games—in particular, [*Advanced Squad Leader*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Squad_Leader)—welcome here?

---

Background:

- [Rogier](http://stackexchange.com/users/32fc7ddb-2e96-47a0-988f-713049f6fdc0) created an Area51 proposal, [Advanced Squad Leader Rules](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30977/advanced-squad-leader-rules).
- Shortly thereafter, it was closed as a subset of BCG.
- Rogier objected to that in an MSO post, [Request for arguments/considerations on site proposal rejection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86192/request-for-arguments-considerations-on-site-proposal-rejection).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**,

All wargames are welcome!

Our [FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq) defines our covered games as

1. Be playable on or around a table
2. Have objective rules of play and win conditions
3. Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
4. Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

**Advanced Squad Leader** fits all the criteria and we welcome the questions.

Comment: @Dori - Anytime!  I don't spend a lot of time on area51, I'm checking the links you posted and will speak up there too.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

The [very first question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1/) on the entire site was a hard-core wargaming question.

It still doesn't have an answer, by the way...

Comment: @Richard: I'm not really sure if your answer speaks for or against the question if B&CG is the place for hard-core wargames :)

Comment: I'm still missing a good chunk of rep that I spent trying to get that answered :(  I also pinged my old friends that played a ton of WiF but was unable to get them to respond.  Sorry!

Comment: @Rogier - I won't deny we have a bit of a chicken and egg syndrome working against us here.  I believe that if we can get some more interesting questions, the people will follow.

Comment: @Pat - Yes, I agree.

Comment: @Rogier Neither am I really sure.

Comment: @Pat Yep, it's a really hard question.  Came up in a game a friend was playing, and I think it was answered on the WiF-list.